# ADB over TCPIP connects, but no command works after connection has been done

Tags: adb, android-emulator, virtualbox, genymotion

I'm developing an Android app.

The so-called app is being developed inside a Windows 7 Pro X64 VirtualBox machine which has a *bridged connection* with the host machine (a Windows 8.1 Pro X64).

In the other hand, I've installed Genymotion Android emulator.

When I run the following commands, everything works fine until I want to perform a `adb install`:

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 192.168.1.5
```

If I perform a `adb install X.apk` (where *X* is the name of the whole package), the command never ends.

Also, I've completely disabled Windows Firewall in both host and guest machine.

Finally, if I perform a `adb devices` command, it says the device is connected:

```
List of devices attached
192.168.1.5:5555        device
```

I can't figure out what's going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3-4 days of trial-error I've found what's the source of the issue...

It has something to do with virtualized ethernet adapter hardware. When I switched to Virt IO and I installed the driver in my Windows 7 guest machine, ADB has started to work as expected!

Conclusion: if you want to debug Android apps from a Windows guest to an emulator or device, configure you VirtualBox machine to use VirtIO (paravirtualized) network and you'll be fine!